# suppress mailto: hover prompt in pdf

Tags: pdf, viewers

I don't have a MWE and am not even sure what package I am include that is responsible for it, but if I include text like:

```
git@github.com:peeterjoot/mathematica.git
```

I end up with a mailto:git@gibhub.com hover prompt when viewing the pdflatex results, which is not what I want (this text doesn't represent an email address).  Does anybody know how to make this show up as plain text?

Comment: Which pdf viewer do you use?

Comment: I see the same effect with SumatraPDF v3.0 and Adobe Acrobat X (both running on Windows 7).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a feature of the pdf reader. Cutting out latex and all packages, the plain TeX

```
aaa

git@github.com:peeterjoot/mathematica.git

bbb

\bye
```

renders as plain text in most of the pdf readers I have available (xpdf, windows 8 thing, firefox....) but adobe acrobat tries to be clever and shows it as a mailto link despite  there being no link in the pdf structure.

In menu `edit/preferences/general/`  you can uncheck `Create links from URLs` and then it stops doing this.

Comment: A small addition: On a MacOSX-specific version of Acrobat and Reader, the menu sequence is `[Acrobat/Reader] -> Preferences -> General`.