# Unnecessary hyperlink comes, how to remove it? Please

Tags: hyperlink, remove

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{crop,palatino,mathpazo,graphicx,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,makeidx,array}%
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-qtree, tikz-qtree-compat}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{xspace}%
\usepackage{bussproofs}%

\usepackage{cgloss4e,gb4e}%

\RequirePackage[bookmarks=false,colorlinks=false,breaklinks,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=black,hidelinks,%
]{hyperref}%
\RequirePackage{breakurl}%
\makeatletter
\urlstyle{rm}%
\def\url@acsstyle{%
  \def\UrlSpecials{%
    \do\/{\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar`/}%
    \do\~{\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar`~}%
    \do\.{\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar`.}%
    \do\,{\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar`,}%
    \do\-{\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar`-}%
    \do\_{\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar`_}%
    \do\?{\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar`?}%
    \do\#{\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar"23}%
    \do\%{\Url@percent}%
    \do\={\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar`=\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty}%
    \do\&{\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty\mathchar`&\penalty\UrlBreakPenalty}%
    \do\ {\Url@space}\do\^^M{\Url@space}%
    \Url@force@Tilde}%
}
\urlstyle{acs}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}
\newcommand{\Xmark}{\ding{53}}

\newcommand{\PP}{{\.{p}}}
\newcommand{\K}{\d{k}}
\newcommand{\LL}{\textlambda}
\newcommand{\LI}{\d{\textlambda}}
\newcommand{\E}{\textipa{@}}
\newcommand{\R}{\textipa{K}}
\newcommand{\W}{\textipa{\super w}}
\newcommand{\I}{\textipa{P}}
\newcommand{\C}{\textipa{\d{c}}}
\newcommand{\Ch}{\v{c}}
\newcommand{\CCh}{\d{\v{c}}}
\newcommand{\Sh}{\v{s}}
\newcommand{\SSh}{\d{\v{s}}}
\newcommand{\Zh}{\v{z}}
\newcommand{\ZZh}{\d{\v{z}}}
\newcommand{\Shh}{\^{s}}
\newcommand{\SShh}{\d{\^{s}}}
\newcommand{\Zhh}{\^{z}}
\newcommand{\Dzh}{\textipa{\v{Z}}}
\newcommand{\Dz}{\textipa{Z}}
\newcommand{\TShh}{\textipa{\t{t\text{\^{s}}}}}
\newcommand{\TSShh}{\textipa{\t{t\text{\d{\^{s}}}}}}%Bzhedug affricate
\newcommand{\X}{\textipa{X}}
\newcommand{\G}{\textipa{G}}

\newcommand{\abs}{\textsc{abs}}
\newcommand{\add}{\textsc{add}}
\newcommand{\adv}{\textsc{adv}}
\newcommand{\aux}{\textsc{ipf}}
\newcommand{\ben}{\textsc{ben}}
\newcommand{\caus}{\textsc{caus}}
\newcommand{\cnv}{\textsc{cvb}}
\newcommand{\com}{\textsc{com}}
\def\comp{\textsc{comp}}
\newcommand{\cond}{\textsc{cond}}
\newcommand{\coord}{\textsc{coord}}
\newcommand{\dat}{\textsc{dat}}
\newcommand{\dem}{\textsc{dem}}
\newcommand{\dir}{\textsc{dir}}
\newcommand{\dyn}{\textsc{dyn}}
\newcommand{\Emph}{\textsc{emph}}
\newcommand{\erg}{\textsc{erg}}
\newcommand{\habit}{\textsc{habit}}
\newcommand{\hbl}{\textsc{hbl}}
\newcommand{\fut}{\textsc{fut}}
\newcommand{\inadv}{\textsc{inadv}}
\newcommand{\indef}{\textsc{indef}}
\newcommand{\Inf}{\textsc{inf}}
\newcommand{\ins}{\textsc{ins}}
\newcommand{\intr}{\textsc{intr}}
\newcommand{\io}{\textsc{io}}
\newcommand{\ipf}{\textsc{ipf}}
\newcommand{\Lim}{\textsc{lim}}
\newcommand{\lnk}{\textsc{lnk}}
\newcommand{\loc}{\textsc{loc}}
\newcommand{\mal}{\textsc{mal}}
\newcommand{\Mod}{\textsc{mod}}
\newcommand{\msd}{\textsc{msd}}
\newcommand{\Neg}{\textsc{neg}}
\newcommand{\nml}{\textsc{nml}}
\newcommand{\obl}{\textsc{obl}}
\newcommand{\pl}{\textsc{pl}}
\newcommand{\poss}{\textsc{poss}}
\newcommand{\pot}{\textsc{mod}}
\newcommand{\pp}{\textsc{pp}}
\newcommand{\pr}{\textsc{pr}}
\newcommand{\pred}{\textsc{pred}}
\newcommand{\pst}{\textsc{pst}}
\newcommand{\q}{\textsc{q}}
\newcommand{\re}{\textsc{re}}
\newcommand{\rec}{\textsc{rec}}
\newcommand{\refl}{\textsc{refl}}
\newcommand{\rel}{\textsc{wh}}
\newcommand{\sml}{\textsc{sml}}
\newcommand{\sg}{\textsc{sg}}
\newcommand{\tmp}{\textsc{tmp}}
\newcommand{\trm}{\textsc{inc}}
\newcommand{\wh}{\textsc{wh}}
\newcommand{\nwh}{\textsc{nwh}}
\newcommand{\BF}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\TS}[1]{\textsubscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\TSS}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\LT}[1]{{\Large #1}}
\newcommand{\LLT}[1]{{\LARGE #1}}
\newcommand{\BI}[1]{\textit{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\FS}[1]{{\footnotesize #1}}
\newcommand{\SC}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\BFSC}[1]{\textbf{\textsc{#1}}}
\newcommand{\citeposs}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s (\citeyear{#1})}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\VAN}[3]{#2}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex \begin{xlist}
\ex \gll \BF{s\E}- \fbox{q-} \hspace*{1pt}j\E- \Sh'a {-\R}\\
\BF{1\sg.\abs}-\, \hspace*{1.5pt}\dir- 3\sg.\erg- bring {-\pst}\\
\glt `He/She brought \BF{me (direct object)}.' \label{qedo}

\ex \gll \BF{s\E}- \fbox{qe-} \K\W a -\R\\
\BF{1\sg.\abs}-\, \hspace*{1.5pt}\dir- go -\pst\\
\glt `\BF{I (intransitive subject)} came here.'\\
(A:137--138) \label{qeisubj}
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

This code works fine, and some `hyperlinks` comes wherever `small cap font` comes, refer below image:

[image]

Really not sure from where it comes. Please suggest what went wrong. I am using `Windows10` and `PDFLaTeX`...

Eventhough I've not used the `hyperref` package also, this problem coming, and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,array}%
%\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-qtree}

\usepackage{cgloss4e,gb4e}%
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex \begin{xlist}
\ex \gll \textbf{s\textipa{@}}- {q-} \hspace*{1pt}j\textipa{@}- \v{s}'a {-\textipa{K}}\\
\textbf{1{{sg}}.{{abs}}}-\, \hspace*{1.5pt}{{dir}}- three{{sg}}.{{erg}}- bring {-{{pst}}}\\
\glt `He/She brought \textbf{me (direct object)}.' \label{qedo}

\ex \gll \textbf{s\textipa{@}}- {qe-} \d{k}\textipa{\super w} a -\textipa{K}\\
\textbf{{{sg}}.{{abs}}}-\, \hspace*{1.5pt}{{dir}}- go -{{pst}}\\
\glt `\textbf{I (intransitive subject)} came here.'\\
(A:137--138) \label{qeisubj}
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Just now, found that this problem due to `\gll` and `\glt`, but not sure how to fix it, please suggest...

Comment: What is now the difference between the two codes? And is `tikz` relevant? Please try to make the example really *minimal*.

Comment: @campa Sorry, initially I believed problem due to may be `hyperref.sty`, after few research now I found that problem lies in `\gll` and `\glt`, so only I kept both codes, shall I remove the first one? Please suggest...

Comment: Could this be a viewer dependant issue? Which pdf viewer did you use to create the screenshot and does it occur with other viewers, as well? (See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230708/134144)

Comment: @leandriis Thanks for your commands, I am using `Adobe Acrobat 8 Professional` to view the PDF...

Comment: By coincidence, you have a `x.x@x.x` structure in the document, which the PDF reader interprets as an email address (as if someone did a regex for "firstname.lastname@somewhere.com". Specifically, from `1sg.` to `threesg.erg`. Remove one of the dots. Try `x.x@x.x` on its own, outside gll, to see.

Comment: Another way is to use `ə` directly, instead of using `\textipa{@}` in that spot.